# connect Internet via Terminal linux

Tags: linux, terminal, internet

I want to write a script-Ubuntu_OS- would connect to a wireless Internet so I need to know how to connect Internet via terminal in Linux.
I tried many suggestions on the Internet but nothing at all

Comment: Please add in some of the things you've tried, not just "I've tried some things".

Comment: you can check this thread here which solved for him but it failed for me :( http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1740726

Comment: I'll assume from the link you're using ubuntu. What sort of protection is on the wireless network, WEP, WPA, whatever?

Comment: that's it....I'm using Ubuntu OS, the wireless encryption is WPA

Answer (score 2):

By your question i assume you want a script to connect to a wi-fi network using a linux script and access internet.

Scan all networks available

iwlist wlan0 scan

```
      Cell 14 - Address: 80:A1:D7:7A:5E:68   <<AP
                Channel:6
                Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"ra"   
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                          36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=000000003621716c
                Extra: Last beacon: 1260ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000472686561
                IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                IE: Unknown: 030106
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
```

From the list select essid of wi-fi netwwork you want to connect

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid ID key KEY
```

if ESSID is "" use access-point

```
iwconfig wlan0 ap AP key KEY
```

script

```
#!/bin/bash
ifconfig wlan0
iwconfig wlan0 ap AP key KEY
dhclient wlan0
```

Comment: I've tried this method but it tells me at the end of operation following:[No DHCPOFFERS received.
Trying recorded lease 192.168.1.100
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
] what does that means ?? then how can I check if it connected or NOT ?!

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

Comment: no dhcpoffers received , means either you havent configured dhcp properly on router or the wi-fi interface is not connected properly .
Check the output of "iwconfig wlan0" to see if its connected properly.
Also you might need to configure ip manually if dhcp is not configured.
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.0.1/24

Comment: Oops...I can't do that even with manually ip :( , anyone can explain step-by-step how will the script can work ?? or even can write the code then upload it ? .does it work with anyone ??

Comment: please anyone can help :'( , after trying this code above the wireless became auto-disconnect every 7-10 minutes :( ,so I changed the password of it to skip the problem.

Comment: There is no reason it should disconnect on its own. check if other processes like NetWorkManager are running on your system "root@x:~# ps aux | grep -i NetworkManager"

Answer (score 0):

You could try using WICD network manager, it has a CLI network manager you can install.

You could also try using the Ceni script from [smxi](http://smxi.org/), which has worked great for me in a few cases where WICD and Gnome-network-manager were not working.

These won't really be a script to start a network connection, but both are accessible from command line and both will let you scan for networks, connect, put in keys, etc. in a nice manner.